# Spring Data JPA Unidirectional OneToOne Mapping does not persist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a Client datatype (representing a customer) which has a principal of type Person and a contact of type Contact (for contact details).

The Client datatype (with the mappings) is:

```
@Entity
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    private String nk;

    @Min(10000000000L)
    private Long abn;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person principal;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
    private Contact contact;

    public Client() {
        this.nk = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    // remaining constructors, builders and accessors omitted for brevity
}
```

Using the Contact as an example (Person is structured the same way)

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String phone;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private String mobile;

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private String fax;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Address address;

    private String email;

    public Contact() {
    }
    // remaining constructors, builders and accessors omitted for brevity
}
```

The Address datatype is also a unidirectional mapping. I could show Person and Address, but I'm pretty sure that nothing new will be understood from them.

Unfortunately, Client is twice the subject of a ManyToOne relationship with Aircraft, through owner and operator fields. I say unfortunately, because it complicates my question. The Aircraft datatype is as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Aircraft {

    @Id
    private String registration;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "casa_code")
    private Casa casa;

    private String manufacturer;

    private String model;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-d")
    private LocalDate manufacture;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Client owner;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Client operator;

    private String base;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "airframe_id")
    private Airframe airframe;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ac_registration")
    private Set<Prop> props;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ac_registration")
    private Set<Engine> engines;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-d")
    private LocalDate lastUpdated;

    public Aircraft() {
    }
    // remaining constructors, builders and accessors omitted for brevity

}
```

The controller method resposible for the save:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AircraftController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AircraftController.class);

    private AircraftService aircraftService;

    @Autowired
    public AircraftController(AircraftService aircraftService) {
        this.aircraftService = aircraftService;
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    @PostMapping(value="/maintainers/{mid}/aircrafts", produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    Response<Aircraft> create(@PathVariable("mid") Long mid, @RequestBody Aircraft request) {

        return Response.of(aircraftService.create(request));
    }
}
```

The service method:

```
public interface AircraftService {

    Aircraft create(Aircraft aircraft);

    // other interface methods omitted for brevity

    @Service
    class Default implements AircraftService {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AircraftService.class);

        @Autowired
        AircraftRepository aircraftRepository;
        @Transactional
        public Aircraft create(Aircraft aircraft) {
            LOG.debug("creating new Aircraft with {}", aircraft);
            if (aircraft.getOwner() != null && aircraft.getOwner().getNk() == null) {
                aircraft.getOwner().setNk(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            if (aircraft.getOperator() != null && aircraft.getOperator().getNk() == null) {
                aircraft.getOperator().setNk(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            return aircraftRepository.save(aircraft);
        }
    }
}
```

and, finally, the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AircraftRepository extends JpaRepository<Aircraft, String> {
}
```

When I supply the following JSON:

```
{
  "registration":"VH-ZZZ",
  "casa":null,
  "manufacturer":"PITTS AVIATION ENTERPRISES",
  "model":"S-2B",
  "manufacture":"1983-01-2",
  "owner":{
    "id":null,
    "nk":"84f5f053-82dd-4563-8158-e804b3003f3b",
    "abn":null,
    "name":"xxxxx, xxxxx xxxxxx",
    "principal":null,
    "contact":{
      "id":null,
      "phone":null,
      "address":{
        "id":null,
        "line3":"PO Box xxx",
        "suburb":"KARAMA",
        "postcode":"0813",
        "state":"NT",
        "country":"Australia"
      },
      "email":null
    }
  },
  "operator":{
    "id":null,
    "nk":"edfd3e41-664c-4832-acc5-1c04d9c673a3",
    "abn":null,
    "name":"xxxxx, xxxxx xxxxxx",
    "principal":null,
    "contact":{
      "id":null,
      "phone":null,
      "address":{
        "id":null,
        "line3":"PO Box xxx",
        "suburb":"KARAMA",
        "postcode":"0813",
        "state":"NT",
        "country":"Australia"
      },
      "email":null
    }
  },
  "base":null,
  "airframe":{
    "id":null,
    "acRegistration":null,
    "serialNumber":"5005",
    "hours":null
  },
  "props":[
    {
      "id":null,
      "acRegistration":"VH-ZZZ",
      "engineNumber":1,
      "make":"HARTZELL PROPELLERS",
      "model":"HC-C2YR-4CF/FC8477A-4",
      "casa":null,
      "serialNumber":null,
      "hours":null
    }
  ],
  "engines":[
    {
      "id":null,
      "acRegistration":"VH-ZZZ",
      "engineNumber":1,
      "make":"TEXTRON LYCOMING",
      "model":"AEIO-540",
      "casa":null,
      "serialNumber":null,
      "hours":null
    }
  ],
  "lastUpdated":"2018-12-16"
}
```

To this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("embedded")
@EnableJpaRepositories({ "au.com.avmaint.api" })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AircraftControllerFunctionalTest {

    private MediaType contentType = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(),
            Charset.forName("utf8"));

    private HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class ServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public CasaFixtures casaFixtures() {
            return new CasaFixtures.Default();
        }

        @Bean
        public ModelFixtures modelFixtures() {
            return new ModelFixtures.Default();
        }

        @Bean
        public MaintainerFixtures maintainerFixtures() {
            return new MaintainerFixtures.Default();
        }

        @Bean
        public AircraftFixtures aircraftFixtures() {
            return new AircraftFixtures.Default();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @Autowired
    private ModelFixtures modelFixtures;

    @Autowired
    private MaintainerFixtures maintainerFixtures;

    @Autowired
    private AircraftFixtures aircraftFixtures;

    Maintainer franks;

    @Autowired
    void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters) {

        this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = Arrays.asList(converters).stream()
                .filter(hmc -> hmc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
                .findAny()
                .orElse(null);

        assertNotNull("the JSON message converter must not be null",
                this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    }


    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();

        franks = maintainerFixtures.createFranksMaintainer();

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

        maintainerFixtures.removeFranks(franks);
        aircraftFixtures.killAircraft(aircrafts);
        UserAndRoleFixtures.killAllUsers(userService, roleService);
    }

    @Test
    public void doCreate() throws Exception {

        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:json/request/vh-zzz.json");
        String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

        mvc.perform((post("/api/maintainers/{mid}/aircrafts", franks.getId())
                .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + ModelFixtures.ROOT_JWT_TOKEN))
                .content(json)
                .contentType(contentType))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.registration").value("VH-ZZZ"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.manufacturer").value("PITTS AVIATION ENTERPRISES"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.model").value("S-2B"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.manufacture").value("1983-01-2"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.owner.id").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.owner.nk").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.owner.contact").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.operator.id").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.operator.nk").isNotEmpty())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.operator.contact").isNotEmpty())
        ;
    }

}
```

I have found that the two ManyToOne mappings in Aircraft are persisted, but the OneToOne mappings are not. Basically these two expectations fail:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.owner.contact").isNotEmpty())
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.payload.operator.contact").isNotEmpty())
```

I have tried a few Cascade options, such as ALL, MERGE etc and it looks like my example is pretty much like others out there. I realise that this is slightly unusual in that Address, Person and Contact do not contain references back to their parents, but I would have thought that this is the point of a unidirectional relationship. Does anyone know how to persist these?

**UPDATE** - On the create method in the AircraftService, I have tried saving the owner and operators separately with:

```
@Transactional
public Aircraft create(Aircraft aircraft) {
    if (aircraft.getOwner() != null && aircraft.getOwner().getNk() == null) {
        aircraft.getOwner().setNk(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    } else if (aircraft.getOwner() != null) {
        if (aircraft.getOwner().getPrincipal() != null) {
            LOG.debug("saving principal");
            Person person = personRepository.save(aircraft.getOwner().getPrincipal());
            aircraft.getOwner().setPrincipal(person);
        }
        if (aircraft.getOwner().getContact() != null) {
            Contact contact = contactRepository.save(aircraft.getOwner().getContact());
            aircraft.getOwner().setContact(contact);
        }
    }
    if (aircraft.getOperator() != null && aircraft.getOperator().getNk() == null) {
        aircraft.getOperator().setNk(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        if (aircraft.getOperator().getPrincipal() != null) {
            Person person = personRepository.save(aircraft.getOperator().getPrincipal());
            aircraft.getOperator().setPrincipal(person);
        }
        if (aircraft.getOperator().getContact() != null) {
            Contact contact = contactRepository.save(aircraft.getOperator().getContact());
            aircraft.getOperator().setContact(contact);
        }
    }

    return aircraftRepository.save(aircraft);
}
```

I did this on the supposition that JPA doesn't know what to do with references to objects that don't exist yet.

But no change.

Other than saving the Contact and Person ids, this change makes no difference to the save repository, which still fails to link the Client to either the Contact or Person. Do I have to save the Contact and Person in a separate transaction, and then save the Client?

This is killing me: what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed CascadeType.MERGE on the Aircraft entity:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Client owner;

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Client operator;
```

Essentially, when JSON is input to a create operation, it appears to be indistinguishable from a MERGE operation (where a new entity is created and put under management, unlike PERSIST) and so a MERGE operation is passed into Client, not PERSIST (as I would have expected). This is why Person and Contact were not being persisted. I still don't understand why JSON input is being treated like a merge though - it doesn't make sense.